# Mysql replication slave is not sysnc gettting error Slave_SQL_Running: No Error executing row event: 'ABC is missing for table

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication

MySQL replication was set up using docker-compose mysql:8.0.20 as the current running DB master. All databases had a size of 50GB. After a few days, the slave was down for 6 hours and was unable to sync.

Tried to reset slave and add but getting the same error.

Can anyone help please!

Looking for solution answers from who is expert in MySQL replication.

Comment: Mysql produces always an error log, try to find it

Comment: Unable to get logs, please suggest other way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708213/enable-logging-in-docker-mysql-container. Read this